# Doubly linked list alternative implementation

Tags: c, data-structures

Is there any other way to implement the following structure of doublylinked list to reduce the space of one extra pointer variable?

```
   struct Node
   {
      int data;
      struct Node* right;
      struct Node* left;
   }
```

Comment: If a pointer on your system takes more memory than `int` (say 8 bytes against 4) then one way to reduce the memory usage would be to define an array of nodes, and use the array index as the linkage information instead of a pointer. If the array was obtained by dynamic allocation, that can be `realloc`ed when you run out of available nodes. I have successfully used this technique for another reason - speed, and maintain a linked list of available nodes. When a new node is needed, it is taken from that list, if any, or the next array element.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah, I agree, but is there any other way so that we could write that structure with the help of only a single structure pointer variable?

Comment: @interjay Got it!